# Nginx location block with if but where is the else?

Tags: nginx-location, nginx-config

Need to redirect a url with variable to another domain name. The following code works when it matches but fails when it does not match.

For example it works when the request is https://old.example.com/test/place?id=2

Fails when the request is for https://old.example.com/test/place?id=1

Need https://old.example.com/test/place?id=1 to just pass through and only catch id=2.

What is missing in the configuration? What did I miss?

```
    location = /test/place {
            if ($request_uri ~ ^/test/place\?id=2) {
                    return 301 https://new.example.com/test/place?id=2;
            }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Found the solution with the help from the nginx mailing list member, Patrick. Here is the link to the conversation.

[The mailing list link to the solution](https://forum.nginx.org/read.php?2,285917)

The final solution is as follows.

```
        if ( $request_uri = "/test/place?id=2" ) {
            rewrite ^ https://new.example.com${uri}?${args}? last;
    }
```